# connection between google colab and amazon DocumentDB to insert data using python code

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, pymongo, aws-documentdb

Is it possible to connect a documentDB cluster with a google colab python program? 
I want to store a dic in DocumentDB but unable to connect and insert data in MongoDB

Thank You

Comment: Which are you using - DocumentDB or MongoDB? IIRC DocumentDB's MongoDB emulation is for version 3.8 which is legacy. Edit your question with more details and include the code and error.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DocumentDB requires your client or application to be in the same VPC as that of DocumentDB cluster's VPC. For connecting from google colab or outside the cluster's VPC you can use a SSH tunneling or port forwarding. Refer to following documentation link for more details : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html.

Also refer to python code example for programmatically connecting to a TLS-enabled DocumentDB cluster at : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled